# Input type JSON html or angular

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to create a form field which takes input as JSON. For that I created one input form field as text and pass value as JSON.

```
Static Tags: <input type="text" name="staticTags">
```

In the input fiedl form I am directly passing `{"tag1":"value1"}`

After submit I am getting the data as `"{"tag1":"value1"}"`, instead I want the data as `{"tag1":"value1"}`. Do we have a way to have a text/JSON data without coat on left and right end?

Comment: use JSON.parse()

Comment: Actually I am sending more complex form, so I can't modify in component class or the form submit function. Only I will be able to modify in HTML. Any way I can implement in HTML itself?

Comment: It's not that there're only additional "quotes" at the beginning and end of the string, it's a totally different thing. `"{'tag1':'value1'}"` is just a plain string, `{"tag1":"value1"}` represents a JavaScript object. To convert the between these two formats you have to use JSON.parse at some place (and JSON.stringify to convert obj=>string). You may put it in your component to make it available in the html template though